# Suggest template for Joomla membership site

Tags: templates, joomla, membership

I need to build a membership site using Joomla 2.5

For membership I'm using Membership Pro plugin from ossolutions team.

Please suggest me a premium template to use with Joomla 2.5 for membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest looking through the [Yootheme](http://yootheme.com) and [Rockettheme](http://rockettheme.com) websites. I have always used their templates for my websites and always will.

Yootheme Demo site: http://www.yootheme.com/demo/

Rockettheme Demo site: http://demo.rockettheme.com/

I just find they bring a certain uniqueness to Joomla template designs and their support has always been first class.

Comment: I was searching on Google for membership template, But found no perfect template. So I asked here if anyone has already used some template

Comment: @HarpreetK. well the extension you're using should blend in with the template like most extensions, therefore you should be looking for a Joomla template, not Membership template. Check out the links I sent you and I'm sure you will find something you like.